# Building palisade with Lego bricks

Tags: discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations, recursion, pattern-recognition

I have problem solving the following questions:

1. I have infinite amount of Lego bricks with 6 and 8 studs in length. I want to build a palisade that has the length of 48 studs . In what ways can I choose Lego bricks so that it fits perfectly?
2. If I want to build a really long palisade, say 480 studs, in how many ways can I do that?

My thoughts: I came to the conclusion that (6 Lego bricks of 8 studs), (8 Lego bricks of 6 studs) and (3 Lego bricks of 8 studs and 4 Lego bricks of 6 studs) are the only ways to get a palisade that has the length of 48 studs. I don't know if it requires calculation to get those numbers, I just made some tests and came up with these numbers.

I have 3 cases (see above) and somehow I think that I have to see/get a pattern out of these cases and that pattern should be recursive? (I think?)

I don't know how to start solving this and I cant see any pattern from my cases. I have tried solving it as a diophantic equation but the results did not say me anything.

Any tips and advice will help!

Comment: What is a palisade ?

Comment: @Donald It is a stockade

Comment: What is a stockade ?

Comment: @Donald google it

Comment: Does "6 knobs" mean [$2\times 3$](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-brick-2-x-3-3002) or [$1 \times 6$](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-brick-1-x-6-3009) or [$2 \times 6$](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-brick-2-x-6-2456-44237)?  Is your palisade just one brick high, so not joined up?

Comment: @Henry The bricks are 1 x 6 and 1 x 8 (in lenght). So I have bricks that have 6 knobs and bricks that have 8 knobs. The palisade should have the total lenght of 48 knobs. The palisade has to be joined up with several bricks so I can get the length of 48 knobs.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to partition $48$ into parts of size $6$ and $8$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
[x^{48}]: \frac{1}{(1-x^6)(1-x^8)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
To do $480$ just replace the $48$ in the above formula.

Alternatively, the solutions of the equation $6a+8b=48$ can be parameterised by $a=4t$ and $b=3(2-t)$, so $t$ can take any value from $0$ to $2$. So there are $3$ solutions.

Comment: I am not good at solving partition formulas. If you could explain some more or maybe guide me, that would be perfect. We didnt learn so much about patrition.